# "Possible Duplicate" deduplication policies

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, duplicate-questions

I think we should give less priority to the "publishing date" compared to "quality" to better handle cases like this one:

**Marked as original**

[iPhone StoreKit - invalid product id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041656/):

```
question vote: 18
question starred: 17
answer accepted: NO
best answer vote: 17
```

**Closed as duplicate**

[StoreKit In App Purchase invalid product identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471454/):

```
question vote: 33
question starred: 14
answer accepted: NO (is possible to accept it ? can't really try it)
best answer vote: 108
```

As you can see it doesn't really matter how many upvotes the answer gets.
From a point of view, this makes sense, it is duplicated, but from another point of view it would have much more sense to close the previous one.

Moreover, it doesn't really looks very useful to close a question, it doesn't really resolve the problem of unifying and centralising the knowledge (due to a the inevitable delay in closing the question).

As fas as I can see it help only to avoid abuses of the system (re-asking a stellar question) but this could be probably archived in many other ways.

I would like to think positive and propose and alternative, however it's not that easy, probably have something to do with upvotes :)

...my 2 cents :)

Comment: I'd just like to note that closed != deleted.  Even if the closed question has a better answer it's not going anywhere.  These questions also might be a candidate for merging, given that they both have highly upvoted answers.

Comment: well, merging would be awesome, but honestly I think it cannot be done without creating a big confusion in the reader's mind. I think it would be quite easy to have an OT answer.

Comment: I am wary of merging in the general case, but for these specific questions it's at least worth considering, as they are sufficently similar, and the answers all appear to cover the general case rather than specifically addressing the OP.

Comment: I'd also like to note that upvotes != quality. Of course it's possible but there's not always a direct correlation.

Comment: @Ben: well, i guess it's the best quality index we have, probably for "quality" star it's better, but it's much less used.

Comment: acutaly, I'm thinking that the quality of the question, also the number of answers could be used (that mean the question it's clear... or too easy, don't know)